# designing custom model objects in R

Tags: r

I'm coded up an estimator in R and tried to follow R syntax. It goes something like this:

```
model <- myEstimator(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
```

`model` has the usual stuff: coefficients, standard errors, p-values, etc.

Now I want `model` to play nicely with the R ecosystem for summarizing models, like `summary()` or `sjPlot::plot_model()` or `stargazer::stargazer()`. The way you might do `summary(lm_model)` where `lm_model` is an `lm` object.

How do I achieve this? Is there a standard protocol? Define a custom S3 class? Or just coerce `model` to an existing class like `lm`?

Comment: If I do something like `mod <- lm(x~y, data = data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50)))` then the object `mod` is class 'lm'. You can call `summary()` on that or other packages to get a clean output like `broom` (`broom::glance(mod))`. Is this what you mean? :)

Comment: yeah except now imagine you ran `mod <- customEstimator(x~y)` instead of `lm()`. The question is how do I make `customEstimator()` return an object similar to `lm()` so I can use `summary()` and all that jazz

Comment: ooh I see. Mm I'm sure there is a better answer but try `View(lm)` that shows the code for the function `lm()` and at line 56 I think the class is defined.

Comment: @QAsena good point hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 2):

Create an `S3` class and implement `summary` etc methods.

```
myEstimator <- function(formula, data) {
  result <- list(
    coefficients = 1:3,
    residuals = 1:3
  )
  
  class(result) <- "myEstimator"
  result
}

model <- myEstimator(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
```

Functions like `summary` will just call `summary.default`.

```
summary(model)
#> Length Class  Mode   
#> coefficients 3      -none- numeric
#> residuals    3      -none- numeric
```

If you wish to have your own `summary` function, implement `summary.myEstimator`.

```
summary.myEstimator <- function(object, ...) {
  value <- paste0(
    "Coefficients: ", paste0(object$coefficients, collapse = ", "),
    "; Residuals: ", paste0(object$residuals, collapse = ", ")
  )

  value
}

summary(model)
#> [1] "Coefficients: 1, 2, 3; Residuals: 1, 2, 3"
```

If your estimator is very similar to `lm` (your model is-a `lm`), then just add your class to the `lm` class.

```
myEstimatorLm <- function(formula, data) {
  result <- lm(formula, data)
  
  # Some customisation
  result$coefficients <- pmax(result$coefficients, 1)

  class(result) <- c("myEstimatorLm", class(result))
  result
}

model_lm <- myEstimatorLm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, data = iris)

class(model_lm)
#> [1] "myEstimator" "lm"
```

Now, `summary.lm` will be used.

```
summary(model_lm)
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = formula, data = data)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.25582 -0.46922 -0.05741  0.45530  1.75599 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   1.00000    0.56344   1.775    0.078 .  
#> Sepal.Length  1.77559    0.06441  27.569  < 2e-16 ***
#>   Sepal.Width   1.00000    0.12236   8.173 1.28e-13 ***
#>   ---
#>   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.6465 on 147 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.8677, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8659 
#> F-statistic:   482 on 2 and 147 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You can still implement `summary.myEstimatorLm`

```
summary.myEstimatorLm <- summary.myEstimator

summary(model_lm)
#> [1] "Coefficients: 1, 1.77559254648113, 1; Residuals: ...
```

Comment: super helpful. i didn't realize `summary()` has a bunch of different methods. see `methods(summary)`